# Sum of data frame's rows in range defined by columns

Tags: r

I have an integer based dataframe with positional coordinates in one column and a variable in the second. The coordinates range from 1-10 million, the variables from 0-950 - I'm interested in returning the sum of the variables from ranges defined within a separate frame containing the start and end points of the desired range.

To make things a bit easier to compute I've shortened the example:

```
Data:
a = seq(1,5)
b = c(0,0,1,0,2)
df1 <- data.frame(a, b)

c = c(1,1,2,2,3)
d = c(3,4,3,5,4)
df2 <- data.frame(c,d)

df1:
1, 0
2, 0
3, 1
4, 0
5, 2

df2:
1, 3
1, 4
2, 3
2, 5
3, 4
```

*magic*

```
output:
1,
1,
1,
3,
1,
```

Where magic is pulling the start and end positions in df2 columns 1 and 2 to pass to rowSums for df1 extraction.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried to do for this magic trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** @Frank's data.table solution: short and fast.

```
df2[, s := df1[df2, on=.(a >= c, a <= d), sum(b), by=.EACHI]$V1]

    # output
       c d s
    1: 1 3 1
    2: 1 4 1
    3: 2 3 1
    4: 2 5 3
    5: 3 4 1
```

Another way (may be slower but works):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)

## magic function
get_magic <- function(x)
{
    spell <- c()

    one <- unlist(x[1])
    two <- unlist(x[2])

    a <- df1[between(a, one, two), sum(b)]
    spell <- append(spell, a)

    return(spell)

}


# applies to row
d <- apply(df2, 1, get_magic)

print(d)
# output
[1] 1 1 1 3 1
```

Comment: Another data.table approach: `df2[, s := df1[df2, on=.(a >= c, a <= d), sum(b), by=.EACHI]$V1]` Generally, growing things in a loop (with `append` here) is inefficient in R, btw.

Comment: @Frank Took me a while to read up on everything in there, definitely been a great learning experience. Thanks for the elgant solution!

Many thanks to you as well Manish, always great to see things worked in different forms.

Magicians, the pair of you!

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is by using `mapply`. I have used a custom function but one can write an inline function as part of `mapply` statement.

```
mapply(row_sum, df2$c, df2$d)

row_sum <- function(x, y){
  sum(df1[x:y,2])
}

#Result
#[1] 1 1 1 3 1
```

## Data

```
a = seq(1,5)
b = c(0,0,1,0,2)
df1 <- data.frame(a, b)

c = c(1,1,2,2,3)
d = c(3,4,3,5,4)
df2 <- data.frame(c,d)
```

Comment: Mapply looks like it'd be really useful for some other problems I've ecountered. Thanks a lot for your input!